# How to import maxima into sbcl

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, slime, sbcl, maxima

As we know, Maxima is based on common lisp. I'm writing a lisp program working in Maxima; using Maxima procedures. I press argument "maxima -p foo.lisp" to load the lisp file, and it works well. However, I'm poor at programming, so my programs have many bugs. I want to debug my program, but I realize that it is not so easy.

I got used to slimv, a vim-script to extend lisp support of vim. Slimv is an awesome tool, which contains swank to connect between slimv and lisp interpreter, but when I loaded 'start-swank.lisp' in the Lisp Mode of Maxima, it returned an error:

```
>> Error in CONDITIONS::CLCS-LOAD [or a callee]: The variable *LOAD-TRUENAME* is unbound.
```

I realized that it is due to gcl. So I came to search for maxima-sbcl. However, there's no official package of maxima-sbcl. I was disappointed.

I wonder whether I can load the whole maxima into sbcl. If so, I can read it in REPL of swank, and debug my program successfully.

Or is there anybody who has better ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've come across this project, which might be what you're looking for
https://github.com/filonenko-mikhail/embeddable-maxima

This is the [developer's blog](http://filonenko-mikhail.blogspot.com/) (Russian) which mentions usage nuances

Comment: Thanks. Although I found that it is okay to use swank in Maxima, your suggestion is useful. I'll take your advice.

Answer (score 3):

Browsing the Maxima documentation, it seems that the source code can be compiled by SBCL:

> Notes on Lisp implementations for Maxima:
>
> 2  3  Clisp, CMUCL, Scieneer Common Lisp (SCL), GCL (ANSI-enabled only)
>   4 and SBCL can compile and execute Maxima

You might get some traction this way:

```
[1] Load up your SBCL (and default core file).
[2] Load Maxima into that lisp session
[3] Save the core file
[4] Kill the swank server
[5] Replace the old core file with the new core file
[6] Restart the swank server
```

Alternatively, check the 'ports' page on the Maxima site. I found a SBCL fink port of Maxima for OS X there.

Comment: I wonder how to load it. The documentation of Maxima shows that I should recompile Maxima.

Comment: I think either compile from src using SBCL, then load those fasls, or find a SBCL port for your platform, and use those fasls

Answer (score 2):

About rebuilding Maxima with just Lisp, see INSTALL.lisp in the Maxima source code.
http://maxima.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=maxima/maxima;a=tree

The method described by INSTALL.lisp makes use of defsystem. You can, alternatively, use ASDF. Assuming you have the source code unpacked, you should be able to do just

```
(require 'asdf)
(asdf:operate 'asdf:load-op :maxima)
```

and then dump out the Lisp image or launch Maxima immediately,

```
(cl-user::run)
```

Note: probably I've omitted some details about the ASDF approach.

Sorry for the late reply. Leaving this here in case someone finds it by searching.